# Is my SSD starting to fail?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd, bad-blocks

I have Plextor 256 gb M2P which is only 3 years old.
**I tried to make a backup image of my system drive with reflect (macrium) and windows backup but it both fails each time with an IO error.**
Altough my windows is booting and I'm working on my system daily.

I downloaded HD Tune pro and looked at the SMART values and did an error scan.
I had **0.3% bad blocks** and the health status gives a warning at "**Reallocated event count : 27"**
Also **"Interface CRC error count : 17"** gives attention warning.
The wear range is 282645.

I'm guessing the backup software can't read certain blocks and fails..
If I check my M2P 256 Plextor with plextools it says healthy.
I also read a ssd with some bad blocks is normal.
How can I take a backup then :s. 
Tried Chkdsk and it found bad sectors but could not repair because not enough space , altough my SSD is only 75% full.

Comment: SDDs should allow reads even if they no longer can write so if you are getting read errors the device is failing.  Tell your backup software to ignore back sectors

Comment: I did set the option in macrium reflect to ignore bad sectors but it still fails with 1117.. I'm wondering if it is Volume Shadow Copy service which fails somehow. I'm trying to take a backup of the system disk which is constantly active. I'll try to take my system ssd out and connect it to my laptop to take a backup there and see if it fails there. I hope not.